# Nginx substitutions with GZIP responses

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a requirement to do substitutions on reverse proxied responses from servers where GZIP is required and was wondering if there was any way of doing this on NGINX. The main use case is replacing image sources depending on user location.

Obviously, I've looked at the built in subs module(which doesn't support regex) and the open source one (subs filter) [here](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module)

Note in my situation it's not possible for me to control what the upstream has turned on/off, I don't control those servers.

So it would appear that I'd need to disable gzip between proxy and server(via a header I guess?), substitute, and then gzip before sending the response?

Is this even possible and does anyone have an example please?

Comment: Were you looking at the `nginx_substitutions_filter` module? It supports regex if that helps.

Comment: Heya yeah thats the one, yeah but not with GZIP unfortunately, so I was trying to figure out if I could refuse gzip from the server, make changes and then gzip on nginx without touching the upstream

Comment: I wonder if you could do something like this `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";` as a directive.

Comment: Yeah me too, I just wasn't sure if you could do that THEN gzip on in a directive.

Comment: For context this is what I am looking at for which header to use -> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

Comment: Yeah so you're saying chuck that in the server block, then in the location, do the substitution then gzip on before the end of the directive?

Comment: Yeah with the usual `gzip on;` sort of deal in the `nginx.conf` file

Comment: Let me give that a go, might be tomorrow now though, but I hadn't thought of it like that. post an answer and I'll mark as correct when I get back if it works!

Comment: Sounds good to me 